# Creating valid directory string and create folder

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

String prints properly using both string and string_2 but when I want to create folder I get [WinError 3] error: System cannot find right path, the string in mkdir function suddenly have double \
My goal is to create a folder based on current date

**Result when I print strings**
C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\abc\2023\2023.06
C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\abc\2023\2023.06

Code

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import shutil


def archive_machine():
    date=datetime.now()
    date_correct_format = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_correct_format_month = date.strftime('%Y.%m')
    date_correct_format_year = date.strftime('%Y')
    file_name = 'Sales Tracker - archived version' + date_correct_format
    string = r'C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\abc'+'\\'+date_correct_format_year+'\\'+date_correct_format_month
    string_2 = r'C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\abc'+f'\{date_correct_format_year}'+f'\\'+f'{date_correct_format_month}'
    #print(string)
    #print(string_2)
    os.mkdir(string)
    os.mkdir(string_2)

archive_machine()
```

Comment: Check out the `pathlib` module - it's a much more robust and convenient alternative to `os` functions and string manipulation for paths

Comment: I always use forward slashes. Python can figure them out even on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work for you??
Basically getting the string you want to pass (leaving the C:\Users\Desktop bit as standard as don't want to be mistakingly creating another directory like that!) and looping through every element of it to make sure you have a full directory path created.

you may need to install pathlib first as below

```
pip install pathlib
```

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

def path_check(dir_path,set_string):

    def path_creation(dir_path):
        # check if path given is currently a directory
        # if it is move on, if not then create the directory passed
        if Path(dir_path).is_dir():
            print('directory already there')
        else:
            print('missing directory, creating now')
            Path(dir_path).mkdir()
    
    # holder for already made paths
    made_paths = []
    # loop through needed directories given in string
    for s in dir_path.split(sep='\'):
        made_paths.append(s)
        path_to_make = '\'.join(made_paths)
        path_creation(path_to_make)


def archive_machine():
    date=datetime.now()
    date_correct_format = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_correct_format_month = date.strftime('%Y.%m')
    date_correct_format_year = date.strftime('%Y')
    file_name = f'Sales Tracker - archived version {date_correct_format}'
    set_string = 'C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\'
    string = f'abc\{date_correct_format_year}\{date_correct_format_month}'
    path_check(string,set_string )

archive_machine()
```